# How to configure the positioning of optional arguments to a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class whose constructor looks like this:

```
GlslProgram(const char* vertex_shader_path, const char* fragment_shader_path, const char* tess_control_shader_path = "", const char* tess_eval_shader_path = "", const char* geom_shader_path = "");
```

The final three parameters are all optional as a `""` is used as a default parameter.

However, because C++ doesn't support positional arguments, if one wants to call the constructor without `tess_control_shader_path` and `tess_eval_shader_path` but with `geom_shader_path` they have to pass in two positional `""` arguments (as opposed to `nullptr` or something more clear).

Is there a clean or simple way to get rid of this? Put another way: is there a way to make specific parameter placement unnecsary?

I am looking at the [named constructor idiom](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html) but I do not love that idea because in this case, the naming convention wouldn't really make sense (i.e. `GlslProgram::withGeometryShader`, `GlslProgram::withTesselation`) doesn't seem to make sense.

Ideally I would have something like:

```
GlslProgram().vertex_path("path")
             .fragment_path("path")
             .geo_path("path")
             .tesselation_path("path");
```

but the issue here is that there is a final initialization step that needs to happen when all parameters are done (all file paths done) and so I don't see how I would know what the final 'path' in the chain is.

Comment: If you can "skip" the allegedly required parameters, then it seems that technically all of the parameters are optional.  Why have them all in the constructor to begin with?  Could you not just have them as member variables with accessor functions and then call an initialization method after you've set which ones you want?

Comment: Another option is to have the constructor take an object that has those paths as members with default values

Comment: @amnesia the first two parameters can not be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a clean or simple way to get rid of this? Put another way: is there a way to make specific parameter placement unnecsary?

The simplest thing I can think of is to provide the following class design with chainable setters for the optional parameters:

```
class MyClass {
    int required_param1_;
    int required_param2_;
    int optional_param1_;
    int optional_param2_;
public:
     MyClass (int required_param1, int required_param2) 
     : required_param1_(required_param1)
     , required_param2_(required_param2)
     , optional_param1_() // Use default
     , optional_param2_() // Use default
     {}
     // The 2 following statements are only for emphasis, and can be completely 
     // omitted as well, since the compiler generates these automatically.
     MyClass (const MyClass& other) = default;
     MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other) = default;

     // Class getter / setter declarations
     int required_param1() const { return required_param1_; }
     int required_param2() const { return required_param2_; }
     int optional_param1() const { return optional_param1_; }
     MyClass& optional_param1(int value) { 
         optional_param1_ = value;
         return *this; }
     int optional_param2() const { return optional_param2_; }
     MyClass& optional_param2(int value) { 
         optional_param2_ = value;
         return *this; }
};
```

That allows you to use the following syntax:

```
MyClass myClass1 = MyClass(1,2 /* <- the required parameters*/)
                          .optional_param1(5)
                          ;
MyClass myClass2 = MyClass(3,4 /* <- the required parameters*/)
                          .optional_param2(24)
                          .optional_param1(42)
                          ;
```

Here's a fully working [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5233635fb4b74915).

> Ideally I would have something like:
>
> ```
> GlslProgram().vertex_path("path")
>              .fragment_path("path")
>              .geo_path("path")
>              .tesselation_path("path");
> ```

My above proposal comes pretty close ...

> but the issue here is that there is a final initialization step that needs to happen when all parameters are done (all file paths done) and so I don't see how I would know what the final 'path' in the chain is.

... the *final initialization* step is still needed and realized with the copy constructor. Though you can rely on the compiler's optimization capabilities and that *copy elision* would take place there.